# Current Page element not passing in jQuery Bootgrid Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, jquery-bootgrid

I am using jQuery Bootgrid, I got 2 problems on Pagination, This is my javascript code

1. From below code data method is passing as **GET**, even I didn't mention GET in my code.(I know default method **POST**), Also I have tried to make it as POST method in ajax setting, Not working
2. While using below code, 1st-time load **current** is passing as 1, so 1st-page showing without any issue,  When I click on Pagination, **current** page element not passing so the whole list of table data showing but all the other data's passing correctly

**current is missing**
From console: GET http://localhost/do_dubai/vat_invoice/get_list/?rowCount=200&searchPhrase=&date_from=&date_to=&status=

```
var grid = $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
            ajax: true,
            rowCount: [200, 100, 50, -1],
            url: "http://localhost/do_dubai/vat_invoice/get_list/",
            post: function ()
            {
                date_from = $("#date_from").val();
                date_to = $("#date_to").val();
                status = $("#status").val();
                return {
                    "date_from": date_from,
                    "date_to": date_to,
                    "status": status
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer that I have **changed the jquery library 1.7.1 to 2.1.4**, then It's working fine, So If someone using old version of Jquery better upgrade to latest version, I think this will help someone